# Sort By field float

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have an app in backbone where I want to sort a collection in base a float filed, but instead of make something like this:
- 9.90
- 12.50
- 100.50
- 110.50

sort result like this:
- 100.50
- 110.50
- 12.50
- 9.90

this is my model:

```
 LanguageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

my collection:

```
 LanguageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: LanguageModel,
            sort_key: 'price', // default sort key
            initData: function(data){
                return data;
            },
            comparator: function (item) {
                return item.get(this.sort_key);
            },
            sortByField: function (fieldName) {
                this.sort_key = fieldName;
                this.sort();
            }
        });
```

my view:

```
var TourView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        initialize: function(){ 
            this.collection_language = new LanguageCollection(); 

            var self = this;
            var success = function(){
                self.render(); 
            };
            var lang = this.importLanguages();

            $.when( lang).done(success);
        }, 
        importLanguages: function(){
            var languages = this.collection_language.initData(jQuery.parseJSON($('#json-languages').html()));
            this.collection_language.set(languages);

            return true;
        },
        render: function(){
            $.each(this.collection_language.models, function( key, value ) {
                value.attributes.price = parseFloat(value.attributes.price).toFixed(2);
            });

            this.collection_language.sortByField('price');
            console.log(this.collection_language);
        } 
    });
```

Into my view I have tried to parse the collection and convert price in float to order but it doesn't solve my problem

```
$.each(this.collection_language.models, function( key, value ) {
                    value.attributes.price = parseFloat(value.attributes.price).toFixed(2);
                });

                this.collection_language.sortByField('price');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem, is `toFixed(2)` inside the order function.

I have change this:

```
$.each(this.collection_language.models, function( key, value ) {
     value.attributes.price = parseFloat(value.attributes.price).toFixed(2);
});
```

to this:

```
$.each(this.collection_language.models, function( key, value ) {
     value.attributes.price = parseFloat(value.attributes.price);
});
```

Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Seems like sort logic is ok. Sorting by others fields are working as expected?
I just want to suggest to convert a price on initialization step.
And the best place to do this is a model's `parse` method:

```
parse : function (data) {
  data.price = +data.price;
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Yes other sorting working fine. Only this is a float field.  As soon as possible i addyour suggestion tThanks